# Access column name for a specific value in GREL/Open Refine (or R, Python)

Tags: python, r, openrefine

I'm trying to access the value of a column name for a specific cell in Open Refine, so I can replace the value of the cell with the column name. I'm aware of the variable `row.columnNames` that returns ALL column names but is there a way to return just the one for the current cell?

I'm trying to change a CSV from this:

```
      Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
Row1          1       2
Row2  1
```

to this:

```
      Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
Row1          Col 2   Col 3
Row2  Col 1
```

with a cell transformation like `if(value != NULL, GetColumNameForCurrentCellSomehow, NULL)`

If it's easier, I could also use R or Python to achieve this goal, but I have not found a straightforward way to do it there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try columnName

if(value != NULL, columnName, NULL)

This does not seem to be documneted or available under the help tab. I found it by looking at: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/c103cdcbff49cde90409855d45f4e50b5a8349d1/main/src/com/google/refine/expr/ExpressionUtils.java#L84

Comment: This worked. Thank you! It's really a shame OpenRefine/GREL isn't documented better.